# PHP - Playing video from dynamic directory path - strange error

Tags: php, video, directory, mime-types, fopen

I am attempting to include an avi video in a webpage. The video is held outside the webroot folder for security and is dynamically loaded using PHP (see full code below).

A sample full path is '/Users/me/project/1/video/test1.avi';

The page is experiencing a strange error. I build the path to the file using the following statement:

```
$pic = $CFG->dataroot."/".$COURT->id."/".$preview;

//($CFG->dataroot = '/Users/me/project')
//($COURT->id = 1 - a number representing the folder name.)
//($preview = 'video/test1.avi' - or the location of image/video)
```

This works for images but fails to load the video showing just the video controls and 'loading...'

EDIT: I have echoed $COURT->id and the variable 1 is being passed correctly

If I change the code and directly specify the directory by removing $COURT->id it works for both video and the images.

```
$pic = $CFG->dataroot."/1/".$preview;  //- works
```

Any ideas why this might be?

Thanks in advance Steve

(I am testing on a Mac using Apache and Safari.)

**Full code:**

```
<?php
$preview = $_GET['preview'];

//works with images but not video
//$pic = $CFG->dataroot."/".$COURT->id."/".$preview;

//works but the folder '1' needs to dynamic i.e. var $COURT->id
$pic = $CFG->dataroot."/1/".$preview;

if ( isset($_GET['preview']) ) {
    if (file_exists($pic) && is_readable($pic)) {
        // get the filename extension
        $ext = substr($pic, -3);
        // set the MIME type
        switch ($ext) {
        case 'jpg':
            $mime = 'image/jpeg';
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $mime = 'image/gif';
            break;
        case 'png':
            $mime = 'image/png';
            break;
        case 'avi':
            $mime = 'video/avi'; //$mime = 'video/x-msvideo';
            break;
        case 'doc':
            $mime = 'application/msword';
            break;
        case 'tif':
            $mime = 'image/tiff';
            break;
        default:
            $mime = false;
    }
    // if a valid MIME type exists, display the image
    // by sending appropriate headers and streaming the file
    if ($mime) {
        header('Content-type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-length: '.filesize($pic));
        $file = @ fopen($pic, 'rb');
        if ($file) {
            fpassthru($file);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: have you tried echoing the `$COURT->id` variable, make sure it holds a value

Comment: then try to echo `$pic`

Comment: Thanks Vladkras - checked it. $pic gives the correct path. Images load ok but when I request a video it fails. Replace $COURT->id with 1 and both images and video work. $COURT->id is definitely sending 1 or the images wouldn't work. It can't be a problem on the page sending the request as the vars are coming through ok.  It just doesn't like the dynamic folder name when it comes to video??!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, when images are sent as $preview (on page before where link to preview is), courtid is sent dynamically to next page, and its OK.

But when video is sent as $preview - courtid its not se(n)t.

Why not, we cannot see in these codes, but codes before, ones that triggers this (play) function.

Try to echo courtid on a page where video should play to check out if it is set as 1 and thats it.

I simply cannot find any other logical solution.

Comment: Hi Xfile & Liam - thanks for the comments, yes ( I should have said)  I have echoed $COURT->id and the full path they are fine. The correct variable is passed and the path is built correctly but for some reason it doesn't work with the video. Like I said, it's a very strange error which has had me baffled.